# How to fund AccountId32?

Tags: accountid

I want to deliver some test where in part of the task is to create accounts and deposit them. I do it in the code below:

```
let account_id_bytes: [u8; 32] = [0u8; 32];
let account_id_1: AccountId32 = AccountId32::new(account_id_bytes);
```

Now I want to fund `account_id_1` like:

`Balances::force_set_balance(RuntimeOrigin::root(), account_id_1, 100).unwrap();`

Function `force_set_balance` expects `u64`, but I have `AccountId32` type. How to fund the account right? My guess is that conversion `AccountId32` to `u64` is not the best approach. Appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that the Substrate runtime is generic over many types, including the `AccountId`.

> Function force_set_balance expects `u64`

If this is the case, then the context in which you are calling `force_set_balance` has been configured for `AccountId = u64`. This is usually the default configuration in tests, which is my guess where this is happening.

You can adjust your configuration to make `AccountId = AccountId32` instead, and that will fix this problem.

You can find an example of that in the Polkadot integration tests: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/polkadot/runtime/common/src/integration_tests.rs

Here you can see:

```rust
use sp_runtime::AccountId32;

type AccountId = AccountId32;
```

This being used in the configuration for `frame_system`:

```rust
impl frame_system::Config for Test {
    type AccountId = AccountId;
    // ...
}
```

And some helpers to make generating unique `AccountId32` more easy:

```rust
fn account_id(i: u32) -> AccountId32 {
    let b4 = i.encode();
    let b32 = [&b4[..], &b4[..], &b4[..], &b4[..], &b4[..], &b4[..], &b4[..], &b4[..]].concat();
    let array: [u8; 32] = b32.try_into().unwrap();
    array.into()
}

fn signed(i: u32) -> RuntimeOrigin {
    let account_id = account_id(i);
    RuntimeOrigin::signed(account_id)
}
```

So ultimately, go and check your `frame_system` configuration and make sure your `AccountId` type is what you want and expect.

Comment: Thank you for extended answer.